# twiiter api/ tweepy comparing a list of two users that I have gathered the followers mentioned users ids

Tags: tweepy

So I am looking at 2 users. I have gathered 100 of their twitter followers and grabbed the user ids of the people that the followers have mentioned. I now have two list of twitter Id's that I want to compare if any of them overlap

```
elonusermentions=[]
for user in elonFirst100FullUsers:
  if not user.protected and user.statuses_count>0:
    Elonmentioneduser=user.status.entities["user_mentions"]
    for Euser in Elonmentioneduser:
      elonusermentions.append(Euser['id'])
elonusermentions
## first 100 elon followers mentioned these people(ID's)


loganusermentions=[]
for user in loganFirst100FullUsers:
  if not user.protected and user.statuses_count>0:
    loganmentioneduser=user.status.entities["user_mentions"]
    for Luser in loganmentioneduser:
      loganusermentions.append(Luser['id'])
loganusermentions
## first 100 logan followers mentioned these people(ID's)
```

I want to compare these lists but am unsure how I would go about it. so far I have tried stuff like this.

```
ELmentions=[]
for user in elonusermentions:
  if user in loganusermentions:
    ELmentions.append(user)
ELmentions
```

I always end up getting a blank list, can anyone help? Im fairly new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using is correct and will give you similar elements from both lists.

You could find similar elements from two list as follow:

Your approach, in list comprehension form -

```
ELmentions = [user for user in elonusermentions if user in loganusermentions]
```

Another is to convert lists into sets and find their intersection -

```
a = set(elonusermentions)
b = set(loganusermentions)
ELmentions = a.intersection(b)
```

You can then convert ELmentions back to list if you want.

You should check your generated lists if they are already empty.
Also check your if statements and put perenthesis where needed.